# How to edit react bootstrap table and save data after editing

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

how to edit table directly on the browser page and save data after reloading page. The table is made using react bootstrap table.screenshot of project is here.[edit and save like in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfdBf.png)

code of my project is here.

```
onAfterSaveCell(value, name){
axios({
method:'post',
url:'https://something.something.com.somewhere/update_something',
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'x-access-token':this.state.token
},
data:{
name:value[name]
}
})
.then((response)=>{
this .getCustomerData();
})
.catch((error)=>{
throw('error',error);
});
 }
```

react bootstrap is here

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.customer_data} search={true} cellEdit={ {
  mode: "click",
  blurToSave: true,
  afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell
 } } >
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="tid" isKey = {true} dataSort={true} width="70">S.No</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="company_name" dataSort={true}>Company Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="contact_address" dataSort={true}>Contact Address</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="contact_person" dataSort={true}>Contact Person</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="contact_number" dataSort = {true}>Contact Number</TableHeaderColumn>
 </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Talking about v3.0.0-beta-11 (I didn't use it before).

There is no problem.

But in your code, you aren't in the right scope.

So just fix it so that `onAfterSaveCell` is called on your Component scope:

```
afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a table using Reactstrap with cell-edit capability. Saving updates occurs with onBlur events. Cell-edit capability is enabled with html contentEditable=true for appropriate cells.

See https://github.com/msb1/reactstrap-functional-table